# Regex: possessive quantifier for the star repetition operator, i.e. \d**

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers

*From the GLib Reference Manual, section ["Regular expression syntax"](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-regex-syntax.html), subsection "Atomic grouping and possessive quantifiers":*

> Consider the pattern `\d+foo` when applied to the string `123456bar`: after matching all 6 digits and then failing to match "foo", the normal action of the matcher is to try again with only 5 digits matching the \d+ item, and then with 4, and so on, before ultimately failing.
>
> If we use `(?>\d+)foo` (called *atomic grouping*) for the previous example, the matcher give up immediately on failing to match "foo" the first time.
>
> When the subpattern for an atomic group is just a single repeated item, as in the example above, a simpler notation, called a "possessive quantifier" can be used: `\d++foo`

My question is: is there any reason why there is no equivalent for the star (`*`) repetition operator?

Example in Java:

```java
final String in = "123456";
// "plus" (+)
System.out.println(in.matches("\\d+"));     // true
System.out.println(in.matches("(?>\\d+)")); // true
System.out.println(in.matches("\\d++"));    // true
// "star" (*)
System.out.println(in.matches("\\d*"));     // true
System.out.println(in.matches("(?>\\d*)")); // true
System.out.println(in.matches("\\d**"));    // exception
```

The exception stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 3
\d**
   ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1878)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:928)
    at java.lang.String.matches(String.java:2090)
```

Comment: do you mean `star` operator instead of `start`? `\d*` here `*` matches `\d`, then you have another `*` which matches nothing. If you do `.*`, then it will match any character any number of times (if I recall correctly, `.` matches all except `\n` and may be few other things).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `+` to anything to make a possessive quantifier (it's not "doubling the quantifier"). So

```
System.out.println(in.matches("\\d*+"));
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't look at it that way... Thanks :)